# How to import libraries or the prelude into the context in which GHC.runGhc runs

Tags: haskell, ghc

I'm trying to evaluate some dynamic code with `GHC.dynCompileExpr`, as below.

```
module Main where

import Data.Dynamic
import GHC
import GHC.Paths as GHP
import GHC.Types
import GHC.Prim
import GHC.Num

main :: IO ()
main = do
  dynval <- GHC.runGhc (Just GHP.libdir) $ do
    setSessionDynFlags =<< getSessionDynFlags
    GHC.dynCompileExpr "[3,2,4,0]::Integer"
  let val = fromDynamic dynval :: Maybe [Integer]
  putStrLn $ show val
```

When I run it, however, it fails with the error: *Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘Integer’*. It seems in the context in which `GHC.dynCompileExpr` runs, no libraries are available, not even the prelude. How would I go about importing a library or the prelude into this context? Including an `import` statement in `GHC.dynCompileExpr` just results in a parse error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this took me a while to figure out, but I seem to have found a way to get it to work.

```
module Main where

import Data.Dynamic
import GHC
import GHC.Paths ( libdir )
import GHC.Types
import GHC.Prim
import GHC.Num
import DynFlags

main :: IO ()
main = do
  dynval <- GHC.runGhc (Just libdir) $ do
    dflags <- getSessionDynFlags
    setSessionDynFlags dflags
    setContext [ IIDecl $ simpleImportDecl (mkModuleName "Prelude") ]
    GHC.dynCompileExpr "[3, 2, 1, 0] :: [Prelude.Integer]"
  let val = fromDynamic dynval :: Maybe [Integer]
  putStrLn $ show val
```

The solution seems to be in the following line:

```
setContext [ IIDecl $ simpleImportDecl (mkModuleName "Prelude") ]
```

This brings Prelude into context and the expression is evaluated correctly, giving the output:

```
Just [3,2,1,0]
```

I got this code from [here](http://www.stephendiehl.com/posts/ghc_01.html). I hope this helps!